# When should I delete my own question?

Tags: support, answers

I asked [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7420/login-to-computer-with-2-different-passwords) question recently.

Now, an answerer has, practically, said that what I want is not possible because the OS doesn't allow it.

I understand this, but I'm unsure whether I should delete the question, or leave it? If it's not possible, then it won't be of any use to future users, will it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you want is impossible, that's useful information. It'll help other people who want to do the same thing, so that they won't also struggle for a while to accomplish the impossible.

Someone could also propose a workaround. And indeed the [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7422) that you received does.

Generally speaking, you should delete your question if its premise turns out to be mistaken (for example if the only reason you asked was because you misread the documentation of a program). If the answer turns out not to be what you hoped, there's no reason to delete it.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep it and look into the workaround

Comment: +1 It is difficult to know a piece of software so perfectly that you know exactly what are all the things it allows, and what things are not doable without third-party software.